# How can I create 3D graphics like this in Blender? (Vintage 80s/90s 3D graphics)

Tags: rendering, lighting

How could you achieve this look (simple, 90s 3D with minimal lighting and shading) in Blender? Rendering it at a small size is a given. Any other ways to make it look like this?

https://www.reddit.com/r/vintagecgi/comments/mo97aj/mallflyfli_1992/
[image: Additional picture]
[image: MALLFLY - 3D render of a simple geometric mall]
[image: Geometric shapes]

Comment: Thank you. But I was more specifically referring to the link attached, which seems to be even more crude.

Comment: even that is an issue. Should the content the link points to be removed the question has very little context.

Comment: The graphics look similar to StarFox or early PS1 games. The thing I am looking for specifically is shading/lighting.

Comment: Please [edit] any additional information into question. Would recommend some  images (inline not links to).